# What are the most profitable strategies for selling photos designs?

Tags: selling

What strategy do you recommend to become the most profitable with my photos and designs. Is it selling on a photo selling site like Getty? Opening a Printful shop? Selling on Etsy? Where should I focus my energy and in what order?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a bad question, but it's a hard one to answer. I don't sell any of my photos, so I can't speak from experience. But maybe you should explain what kind of photography you specialise in, and what you are hoping to achieve or what you envisage this business being. Is this going to be your only income or just a sideline thing that is more just a bonus if something sells?

Comment: It's all marketing, marketing, marketing. The more you can convince potential customers that your work is unique and exclusive (regardless of whether your work actually *is* unique and exclusive), the more you'll be able to sell your work for higher prices. It helps if you aim your marketing at the shrinking number of people who are actually willing to *pay* for images instead of just stealing whatever they can find on the internet.

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you make. If you shoot 150 snapshots of everyday things a week, Getty. If you spend 3 months editing one image, then go to the right high end art gallery.

Comment: While I love me some photo biz questions, this one is just too broad. I suggest that you search online for "Business Plan Template" and also "Marketing Plan Template" and fill them out as an exercise. If you have questions along the way, feel free to post - but keep in mind that the details of your business are important to receiving any sort of advice. No one is going to tell you what business to run - you have to decide that for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

An artist and their art is proven by a volume of work. However, the photographer's "volume" is not everything shot but a large volume of the best shots.

So the credible artist is a specialist and the question is, what does the artist specialize in ?

With a speciality then the photographer could have a chance of success with something like the Getty photo websites.

Otherwise, consider selling matted and framed prints physically at shops or flea markets. Nothing is going to be very noticed on-line unless it is something already famous.

Answer (score 1):

When researching my latest course, I visited the Alexa ranking of all of the biggest sites to sell artwork on, and came up with the top websites by traffic.

Here are the top POD sites, According to their Alexa rank: Redbubble, Society6, Cafepress, Zazzle, ArtofWhere, Pixels (Formerly FineArtAmerica, using their rank), Threadless, Spreadshirt, Printful.

Here are the top Stock Photography sites: Adobe stock, Shutterstock, Dreamstime, 123RF, Pond5, Getty Images, iStock, Bigstock, 500px and Alamy.

I recommend that you focus your efforts on these sites. Upload a batch to all of the sites, and see what does best for you.

Comment: Hi Douglas, Welcome to Photography.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience.

Comment: Hey Douglas, thanks for sharing your insight.  Unfortunately I had to edit part of the post as it didn't meet our self promotion criteria.  I can see you have been a contributor on SE and you did disclose your affiliation, but the third criteria is that the promotion needs to directly answer the question.  In this case, while the links would be ok for being a source of more indepth information, you'd really need to provide a bit more substance to the answer on site with them being a reference for additional information unless the user was specifically asking about finding training.